# Merging identical lines in an output

Tags: linux, bash, merge, lines

I'm trying to merge or not repeat the lines in an output using bash but don't want to  grep for it.  I'm not sure how to do it.  I'm trying to do this in Linux:

Before:

113.171.10.13
113.171.10.13
113.171.10.13
113.171.10.13
23.253.228.76
23.253.228.76
23.253.228.76
23.253.228.76
23.253.228.76
23.253.228.76

After:

113.171.10.13
23.253.228.76

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: or `sort -u` if not sorted

Comment: Cool!  Thanks guys!  I just found another way of doing it using:

gawk '!x[$0]++'

And it works!

I'll check out those other commands.  Much appreciated the reply back!

Comment: uniq -d and sort -u works as well!  Thanks again!

Comment: `awk '!x[$0]++'` is better to use if you dont want the file to be sorted, as both `uniq` and `sort -u` require the file to be sorted.

Answer (score 2):

Use unique sort, outputing only the first of an equal run:

```
sort -u
```